# Menu Bar missing in LibreOffice 6 under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice, ubuntu-mate

*desperate Question:*

#### How do I get the menu bar back in LibreOffice 6?

[image]

**Above you see:** LibreOffice 5.1 under my old faithful Ubuntu-MATE 16.04.

**Below you see:** LibreOffice 6.4 under fresh installed Ubuntu-MATE 20.04

If you advise me to use view or settings, please tell me how to get there. `alt-v`, `alt-,` has no effect...

Comment: You probably have enabled "global menus" in Mate (which is set when choosing the Unity layout, and probably also the Mac OSX layout (do not know how it is called). Choose another layout and you will be set.

Comment: I right-click "Add to panel" the global menu and produced the same effect. Removing it from the panel restored the menu to libreoffice instantly. Do you not see that long menu somewhere else on your screen?